# Scala self-typed trait and calling method on supertype

Tags: scala, traits

Lets say I have a class like this

```
class Job(args:String) {

  def config:Map[String,String] = ...

}
```

I want to create a trait that can be mixed in with this class to add more configuration options. So I did something like this

```
trait ExtraConfig { self:Job =>

  override def config = self.config ++ Map("extra","config")
}
```

unfortunately this doesnt compile as self.config becomes self recursive.

I tried doing

```
trait  ExtraConfig  extends Job {}
```

but job is taking a constructor param and I dont know how to thread that through.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `abstract override` modifier, but to use it you need explicitly extend the `Job` class, then in you trait you can use members of your superclass:

```
class Job(args:String) {
  def config:Map[String,String] = Map.empty
}

trait ExtraConfig extends Job {
  abstract override def config =
    super.config ++ Map("extra" -> "config")
}

val job = new Job("name") with ExtraConfig
```